# How do I query an association for non-unique values of a field with SQL/ActiveRecord?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

Honestly I'm not even sure how to describe it in a single sentence, so that title might be way off. Here's what I'm trying to do:

I've got a fairly simple model. User -> Stories -> Comments. That is, a User has_many Stories, and a Story has_many Comments.

What I'm trying to do is only return the stories that:

- Have comments
- Were either created by the current user or have been commented on by the current_user
- But not if the current user is the *only* user to comment on it

What I have so far is:

```
Story.includes(:comments).where("stories.user_id = ? OR comments.user_id = ?", current_user.id, current_user.id)
```

But I have no idea how to do the last condition in SQL. The only thing I could do was use Enumerable methods.

```
@stories.reject! { |story| story.comments.collect(&:user_id).all? { |user_id| user_id == current_user.id }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to have a nested subquery, something like

```
Story.includes(:comments).where("stories.user_id = ? OR comments.user_id = ?) 
    and exists (select 'x' from comments c2 where c2.story_id = stories.id 
    and c2.user_id != ?)",
  current_user.id, current_user.id, current_user.id)
```

Comment: Oh, the OR group was missing parentheses. "(stories.user_id = ? OR comments.user_id = ?) AND EXISTS (select 'x' from comments c2 where c2.story_id = stories.id and c2.user_id != ?)"